# Where to ask about strange behavior on uploading files to some websites?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question which is related to some website portal backend.
I'm not developer of this website, and I'm not part of IT team who maintains this website.
I just want to ask about uploading files problems which can be related to some kind of file verification process during the upload process.

So which Stack Exchange site should I choose to ask on?

Comment: Check [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help) and make sure your question is [on-topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there.

Comment: You could also try their support site.

Comment: If it's related to security and possible implications of it on you, or the site itself, [Information Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) might also fit.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE I had to do that and done today. But I wanted to talk about the problem if my guessing are correct. As you know HeplDesk/Support not always will say to you the true.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 it is some how related but I think that choose decide to use `41686d6564` sugestion